# Which libraries does Jenkins load when I start a pipeline?

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, groovy-grape

I recently ran into the problem that a Java library I loaded through grape was obviously hidden by a dependency of the Jira Plugin ([Which Jersey version runs in Jenkins 2.107.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49407079/927493)). The possibility of such a conflict is also documented in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44378.

This makes me wonder: If my pipeline and the Jenkins plugins live in the same JVM without any separation, I can never know which version of a specific jar/class will be used and it is very difficult to stably run a pipeline.

I can only think of two solutions:

1. I do *not* load external libraries through grape, but put some functionality into REST services which I call from the pipeline.
2. I somehow tell Jenkins to run my pipeline in separation (separate JVM, separate classloader, etc.)

I would prefer (2), but I do not know how to achieve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824805/how-can-i-isolate-my-jenkins-pipeline-groovy-shared-library-classloader